# Why do expressions require double parenthesis?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Consider the following bash code:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 50 ]
do
    echo $i
    i=$(($i+1))     #  <-------
done
```

In the pointed line, why does it matter how many parenthesis are used? The code doesn't work if I write

```
i=$($i+1)
```

Why is it so?

Comment: You can also use the arithmetic expressions to make your loop more compact: `for ((i=1;i<=50;i++)); do echo $i; done`.

Comment: @AdminBee, they also have a double set of parenthesis :)

Comment: In addition, variables inside (( .. )) do not need quoting or $ expansion, which makes them more readable and robust.

Answer (score 9):

For sure, it's quite different. We focus on [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) builtin only:

`$((...))` is an arithmetic substitution. After doing the arithmetic, the whole thing is replaced by the value of the expression. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

Command Substitution: `"$(cmd "foo bar")"` causes the command 'cmd' to be executed with the argument 'foo bar' and `"$(..)"` will be replaced by the output. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

---

## Finally

You can write a better/simpler line than `i=$(($i+1))`:

```
((i++))
```

And for the `loop`:

```
for i in {1..50}; do ...
```

or

```
for ((i=1; i<50; i++)); do ...
```

Comment: Isn't `man bash` a better source for these?

Comment: No, the link provide more examples. But `man bash` is a good ressource too

Comment: `let 'a = 1'` works like `(( a = 1 ))`. Only the latter is more legible and doesn't require the extra quoting. All of `let`, `((...))`, `$((...))` come ksh. Only the latter is specified for POSIX `sh`. `bash` (and `zsh`) also support `$[...]` as that was the syntax chosen in an early POSIX draft I beleive.

Comment: `for i in $(seq 50)` only works if `$IFS` contains newline and doesn't contain digits.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, re. history of `$[...]`, it was just on the bug-bash mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-07/msg00036.html